# ¿ Es posible acceder a las coordenadas mediante un webview?

Tags: android-studio, webview

Estoy iniciandome en Android, y quisiera preguntar, ¿ es posible acceder a la geolocalización u obtención de coordenadas mediante un webview ? ¿ O va toda la obtención de coordenadas desde la web que haga en html ?

Gracias de antemano

Comment: en SO existe una pregunta bastante parecida, quizás te sea de ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5329662/android-webview-geolocation

Comment: Buenos dias Felipe, creo que si es lo que necesito, o se le arrima bastante, ya me has dado una enorme pista sobre ello.